# Crystal Reports "Out-of-range" error when using parameter in the SQL query

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm using CR 2008.

This MSSQL query works when dates are hardcoded like this:

```
select *
from workedHours
where myDateTime.startdate > CONVERT(datetime,Cast('25-12-2011' AS Char (10)), 105)
```

But when I use parameters:

```
select *
from workedHours
where myDateTime.startdate > CONVERT(datetime,Cast({?startdate} AS Char (10)), 105)
```

and provide dates like this:

```
26-12-2011
```

then i get an errror message saying:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a dateTime field resulted in an out-of-range value.

Apparently Crystal Reports does do some conversion on its own. Can I switch this off?

Thanks!

EDIT: fixed it: char 10 was too short for the length char 11 is ok...

Comment: Is `{startdate}` a date parameter or a character parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Varchar(50)` instead of `char(10)` like:

```
CONVERT(datetime,Cast({?startdate} AS varchar (50)), 105)
```

Comment: Well apparantly they both work, the length of char(10) was too short, which i don't understand since 28-10-2011 is 10 characters...

Comment: and what about `startdate` I think it is a `datetime` so it's length might not fit into `char(10)`